# How to run an Apache-Mina SSHD-Server (2.2.0) on Android Pie?

Tags: android, apache-mina, apache-sshd

I'm trying to run an Apache MINA SSHD Server (v. 2.2.0) on an Android Pie (API 28.0) device. I found various post about it running on Android 4 devices, but none of them seems to work on my Android 9 device. So I tried to implement it myself but got stuck at the initialization of the Server with a ReflectionException/NoClassDefFoundError.

When I try to set up the server with SshServer.setUpDefaultServer(); I get this exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljavax/management/ReflectionException;
        at org.apache.sshd.common.util.GenericUtils.peelException(GenericUtils.java:730)
        at org.apache.sshd.common.util.GenericUtils.peelException(GenericUtils.java:728)
        at org.apache.sshd.common.util.security.SecurityEntityFactory$2.getInstance(SecurityEntityFactory.java:134)
        at org.apache.sshd.common.util.security.SecurityUtils.getMessageDigest(SecurityUtils.java:726)
        at org.apache.sshd.common.digest.DigestUtils.checkSupported(DigestUtils.java:53)
        at org.apache.sshd.common.digest.BuiltinDigests.<init>(BuiltinDigests.java:61)
        at org.apache.sshd.common.digest.BuiltinDigests.<clinit>(BuiltinDigests.java:36)
        at org.apache.sshd.common.cipher.ECCurves.<clinit>(ECCurves.java:61)
        at org.apache.sshd.common.keyprovider.KeyPairProvider.<clinit>(KeyPairProvider.java:63)
        at org.apache.sshd.common.signature.BuiltinSignatures.<clinit>(BuiltinSignatures.java:62)
        at org.apache.sshd.common.BaseBuilder.<clinit>(BaseBuilder.java:133)
        at org.apache.sshd.server.ServerBuilder.builder(ServerBuilder.java:165)
        at org.apache.sshd.server.SshServer.setUpDefaultServer(SshServer.java:429)
        at ch.zhaw.init.sshshell.SshShellService.<init>(SshShellService.java:20)
```

From some older posts for Android 4 it seems that this is was a known problem and the solution there was to add $useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy' to gradle and add  to the manifest.xml. I did that but the exception still occurs.

build.gradle file:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    ...
}
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'org.apache.sshd:sshd-core:2.2.0'
    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.6.2'
    implementation 'org.apache.mina:mina-core:2.1.2'
    implementation "org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk16:1.46"
}
```

manifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="ch.zhaw.init.sshshell">
    <application
            android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">
        <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
                      android:required="false" />
        <service android:name=".SshShellService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="StartSshServer"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

My Java-Code:

```
import org.apache.sshd.server.SshServer;
import org.apache.sshd.server.keyprovider.SimpleGeneratorHostKeyProvider;


private static final int PORT = 8022;
private final SshServer sshd = SshServer.setUpDefaultServer(); // Here I get the error
private final SimplePasswordAuthenticator passwordAuth = new SimplePasswordAuthenticator();
private final SimplePublicKeyAuthenticator publicKeyAuth = new SimplePublicKeyAuthenticator();
private final SimpleForwardingFilter forwardingFilter = new SimpleForwardingFilter();
```

It seems that older versions worked, but I search for days and did not find any working example for the newest version. Does anyone has a working example which runs the latest version of Apache Mina SSHD (2.2.0) on Android 9 (without rooting the device)?

or if not is there an alternative SSH-Server (not client - there are many of them) for Android Pie?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this specific failure, it suffices to create a dummy ReflectionException class [(example)](https://gitlab.com/wh0/te/blob/v5/app/src/main/fills/javax/management/ReflectionException.java). Given that the class doesn't even exist, nothing outside of your own code would ever instantiate it, so SSHD's `instanceof ReflectionException` check would never match, and you don't need to program any of its members.

You'll also want to create a dummy MBeanException [(example)](https://gitlab.com/wh0/te/blob/v5/app/src/main/fills/javax/management/MBeanException.java).

Answer (score 0):

the error because of BouncyCastle lib has been deprecated as android9(api level 28).

you can get detail tips from aosp: http://androidxref.com/9.0.0_r3/xref/libcore/ojluni/src/main/java/sun/security/jca/Providers.java#548

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/03/cryptography-changes-in-android-p.html

to solve this problem ,you can follow steps:

1. uninstall BouncyCastleProvider from system default

```
Security.removeProvider("BC");
```

2. install new "BC" custom provider

```
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
```

3. init your mina sshd Service

```
 SshServer sshd = SshServer.setUpDefaultServer();
 sshd.setPort(ssdServerPort);
 ....
```

aosp just compare object to decide if bc provider object is system default provider,so just replace with new bc provider object
:http://androidxref.com/9.0.0_r3/xref/libcore/ojluni/src/main/java/sun/security/jca/Providers.java#341

notes: you must uninstall provider with :`Security.removeProvider("BC")`,before install provider